# react native scrollToIndex does not work on android

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, scroll

I successfully used scrollToIndex for iOS but the same code is not working for android. Any idea?

```
this.list.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: tempIndex, viewOffset:0,viewPosition:0});
```

and my flatlist

```
<FlatList
    ref={(ref) => { this.list = ref; }}
    initialNumToRender={15}
    data={searchData}
    scrollKey={'name'}
    reverse={false}
    itemHeight={30}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
         <List
              item={item} selectItem={()=>this.selectItem(item)}
         />
    )}
    refreshing={isFetching}
    keyExtractor={item => item._id}
    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement [getItemLayout()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.47/flatlist#getitemlayout) so the FlatList will know the position of the index.

Comment: I added getItemLayout to the flatlist now but still there is no action when I call the scrollToIndex. Should I add anything else?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I also implemented  getItemLayout()